# Is it possible to call two different treefrom Firebase realtime database in single Java file?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database looked like this]

Currently, I'm calling reference of "Property" but at the same time I want to call reference of "Geo-fence" also. Is it possible to do that in same Java file? I want data from property and "Geo-fence" to be used in one fragment. Other solutions would be appreciated.

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Property");
refGeo = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Geo-fence");
```

Comment: No not possible

Comment: got any idea how to i get data from the "geo-fence" tree to be used in java files that have other tree called ? @GaneshPokale

Comment: To understand better, you want to query the database in both `Property` and `Geo-fence` nodes and get the same type of object? Please add your database structure for both nodes and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: database picture added @AlexMamo i want to take all data from **geo-fence** and count the distance between lat/lng from **property**

Comment: I understand now, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to your comment, if you need to get the `latitude` and `longitude` from both nodes and compare the distance, assuming that both properties in both places are of type `double` and **not** string, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference geoFenceUidRef = rootRef.child("Geo-fence").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        double geoFenceLat = dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        double geoFenceLng = dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);
        Location geoFenceLocation = new Location("");
        geoFenceLocation.setLatitude(geoFenceLat);
        geoFenceLocation.setLongitude(geoFenceLng);
        Log.d(TAG, geoFenceLat + ", " + geoFenceLng);

        DatabaseReference propertyUidRef = rootRef.child("Property").child(uid);
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    double propertyLat = ds.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    double propertyLng = ds.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    Log.d(TAG, propertyLat + ", " + propertyLng);

                    //Compare
                    Location propertyLocation = new Location("");
                    propertyLocation.setLatitude(propertyLat);
                    propertyLocation.setLongitude(propertyLng);
                    float distance = geoFenceLocation.distanceTo(propertyLocation);
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(distance));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        };
        propertyUidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
geoFenceUidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

If you saved them as strings, please change the above lines of code to:

```
double geoFenceLat = Double.parseDouble(dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(String.class));
double propertyLng = Double.parseDouble(dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(String.class));
```

and

```
double propertyLat = Double.parseDouble(ds.child("latitude").getValue(String.class));
double propertyLng = Double.parseDouble(ds.child("longitude").getValue(String.class));
```

Comment: thank you so much, i have changed your code depending on my needs. i got it working.